# Property does not exist on Type - Angular 15 and TypeScript 4..9.5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have below sample code, causing a issue while running.

[image]

any idea what is wrong with this code base ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check if the recipe service is injected properly in constructor and imported correctly?

Comment: It's an angular Service, no need to inject through the constructor. @PrabhakaranM

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing the declaration part.

[image]